# Recursive functions : Inversing word

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to make a simple function that inverses a string using recursion.

this is what i tried :

```
    def inverse(ch):
        if ch=='' :
            return ''
        else:
            return ch[len(ch)]+inverse(ch[1:len(ch)-1])

    print inverse('hello')
```

And this is what i get :

> line 13, in inverse
>       return ch[len(ch)]+inverse(ch[1:len(ch)-1]) IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Indexes in a string run from 0 to `len-1`. So how could `ch[len(ch)]` be right?

Comment: Break up the line and use temporary variables to work out which index is wrong.

Comment: If you want the last character of a word, use a negative index: `ch[-1]`. And a slice up to the last character is `ch[0:-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
ch[len(ch)-1]+inverse(ch[0:len(ch)-1])
```

Answer (score 3):

You're indexing the string at its length, but remember that indexing is zero based so you'll have to slice at length minus 1 which is the maximum index you can safely use.

You can however choose to be oblivious of the length by using `[-1]` to index the last item:

```
def inverse(ch):
    if ch=='' :
        return ''
    else:
        return ch[-1]+inverse(ch[:-1])

print inverse('hello')
# olleh
```

And you also probably want to keep in mind that slicing with `[::-1]` provides the same result as your recursive function.

Comment: Good that worked for me!, so you can't use ch[len(ch)] to get the last character?

Comment: @Ashref No, you'll have to do that with the minus 1: `ch[len(ch)-1] `

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need recursion here.

```
def inverse(chars):
    char_list = list(chars)
    char_list.reverse()
    return ''.join(char_list)
```